# How to fix "ImportError: Cannot import name X" or "AttributeError: ... (most likely due to a circular import)"?

Tags: python, flask

I'm new to Flask and Python and I'm struggling with circular imports with my auth routes and user routes. I can successfully access other API endpoints except my **auth_routes** endpoints. How can I fix this issue?

My file structure is:

```
app/
    |backend/
        |models/
            |user.py
            |etc...
        |routes/
            |auth_routes
            |etc...
        |app.py
    |frontend/
        ...
```

My **auth_routes** imports from app and models.user
My **user.py** imports db from app

My **auth_routes**:

```
from flask import Blueprint, request, jsonify, abort
from flask_login import login_user, logout_user, login_required
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash
import jwt
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from app import db, app
from models import User

auth_routes = Blueprint('auth_routes', __name__)

@auth_routes.route('/signup', methods=['POST'])
def signup():
  print(request)
  data = request.get_json()
  print(data)

  user_exists = User.query.filter_by(email=data['email']).first()

  if user_exists:
    abort(400)

  if len(data['password']) < 8:
    return jsonify({'message': 'Password must be at least 8 characters long'}), 400

  hashed_password = generate_password_hash(data['password'], method='sha256')
  
  new_user = User(email=data['email'], password=hashed_password, 
            first_name=data['first_name'], last_name=data['last_name'])
  
  db.session.add(new_user)
  db.session.commit()
  
  return jsonify({'message': 'User registered successfully'}), 201

@auth_routes.route('/login', methods=['POST'])
def login():
  data = request.get_json()
  user = User.query.filter_by(email=data['email']).first()
  
  if user and check_password_hash(user.password, data['password']):
    token = jwt.encode({
      'user_id': user.id,
      'exp': datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(days=1)
    }, app.config['SECRET_KEY'], algorithm='HS256')
    
    return jsonify({'token': token})
  
  return jsonify({'message': 'Invalid credentials'}), 401
```

My **app.py**:

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_migrate import Migrate
from flask_cors import CORS
from functools import wraps
import jwt

from routes.auth_routes import auth_routes
from routes.user_routes import user_routes
from routes.event_routes import event_routes
from routes.artist_routes import artist_routes
from routes.venue_routes import venue_routes
from routes.genre_routes import genre_routes

from models.user import User

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app, origins=["http://localhost:3000"], method=["GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE"], allow_headers=["Content-Type", "Authorization"])
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'postgresql://postgres:password@localhost/ticketmaster_clone'
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secretkey'

def token_required(f):
  @wraps(f)
  def decorated(*args, **kwargs):
    token = request.headers.get('Authorization')
    if not token:
      return jsonify({'message': 'Token is missing'}), 401
    try:
      data = jwt.decode(token, app.config['SECRET_KEY'], algorithms=['HS256'])
      current_user = User.query.get(data['user_id'])
    except:
      return jsonify({'message': 'Token is invalid'}), 401
    return f(current_user, *args, **kwargs)
  return decorated


db = SQLAlchemy(app)
app.register_blueprint(auth_routes)
app.register_blueprint(user_routes)
app.register_blueprint(event_routes)
app.register_blueprint(artist_routes)
app.register_blueprint(venue_routes)
app.register_blueprint(genre_routes)

migrate = Migrate(app, db)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run(debug=True, port=8080)
```

I've used Postman to check the endpoints, they work except signup and login. I've also tried signing up through the client side and I get this:

```
signup:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/signup' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.
```